# I can't get python plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I am new to python/qt/matplotlib. I used QtDesigner to get started and I've got everything working other then plot! It seems all the examples used a very different method to call the plot canvas. I'm trying to get the plot inside the QGraphicsView

So with help I was able to get the graph plotted, but now when I call the comboevent def, I get a crash with not error or post?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDate, QDateTime, QTime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random
import matplotlib
import sys
import os
from numpy import arange, sin, pi, to
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):

        Graphs = ["None", "Temperature", "Humidity", "Garage Lights", "Path     Lights", "HVAC Fan", "HVAC Heat", "HVAC Heat Pump", "HVAC Reverse"]
    Graph_Colors= ["Black", "Blue", "Red", "Cyan", "Yellow"]

        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.setWindowTitle("GraphIt")
        Form.resize(805, 585)

        self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(Form)
        self.graphicsView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 10, 631, 361))
        self.graphicsView.setObjectName("graphicsView")

        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2*pi*t)

        figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
        self.canvas.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.graphicsView)
        lay.addWidget(self.canvas)
        self.axes = figure.gca()
        self.axes.set_title("title")
        self.axes.plot(t,s)

        #figure = Figure()
        #self.axes = figure.gca()
        #self.set_title("title")
        #self.plot(t,s)
        #self.canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
        #self.canvas.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)
        #lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.graphicsView)
        #lay.addWidget(self.canvas)


        self.UseCurrentTime = QtWidgets.QRadioButton("Current Time", Form)
        self.UseCurrentTime.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 390, 82, 17))
        self.UseCurrentTime.setObjectName("UseCurrentTime")
        self.UseCurrentTime.setChecked(True)
        self.UseCurrentTime.toggled.connect(self.UseCurrentTimeButton)

        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 390, 266, 178))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")

        self.StartTime = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(self.widget)
        self.StartTime.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.StartTime.setObjectName("StartTime")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.StartTime, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.StartTime.setDate(QDate(datetime.now()-timedelta(days=7)))
        self.StartTime.setTime(QTime.currentTime())

        self.EndTime = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(self.widget)
        #self.EndTime = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(self, QDateTime())
        print (QDate(datetime.now()-timedelta(days=7)))
        self.EndTime.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.EndTime.setCurrentSectionIndex(0)
        self.EndTime.setObjectName("EndTime")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.EndTime, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.EndTime.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
        self.EndTime.setTime(QTime.currentTime())
        self.EndTime.setEnabled(False)


        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(12)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        #Graph1_Label
        self.Graph1_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Graph 1", self.widget)
        self.Graph1_Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Graph1_Label.setObjectName("Graph1_Label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph1_Label, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        #Graph1_Select
        self.Graph1_Select = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        self.Graph1_Select.setObjectName("Graph1_Select")
        self.Graph1_Select.addItems(Graphs)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph1_Select, 0, 1, 1, 1) 
        self.Graph1_Select.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onActivated) 

        #Graph1_Color
        self.Graph1_Color = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        self.Graph1_Color.setObjectName("Graph1_Color")
        self.Graph1_Color.addItems(Graph_Colors)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph1_Color, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.Graph1_Color.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        #Graph2_Label
        self.Graph_Label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Graph 2", self.widget)
        self.Graph_Label2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Graph_Label2.setObjectName("Graph_Label2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph_Label2, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        #Graph2_Select
        self.Graph2_Select = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        self.Graph2_Select.setObjectName("Graph2_Select")
        self.Graph2_Select.addItems(Graphs)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph2_Select, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.Graph2_Select.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        #Graph2_Color
        self.Graph2_Color = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        self.Graph2_Color.setObjectName("Graph2_Color")
        self.Graph2_Color.addItems(Graph_Colors)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph2_Color, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.Graph2_Color.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        #Graph3_Label
        self.Graph3_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Graph 3", self.widget)
        self.Graph3_Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Graph3_Label.setObjectName("Graph3_Label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph3_Label, 2, 0, 1, 1)

        #Graph3_Select
        self.Graph3_Select = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        self.Graph3_Select.setObjectName("Graph3_Select")
        self.Graph3_Select.addItems(Graphs)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph3_Select, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.Graph3_Select.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        #Graph3_Color
        self.Graph3_Color = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        self.Graph3_Color.setObjectName("Graph3_Color")
        self.Graph3_Color.addItems(Graph_Colors)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph3_Color, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.Graph3_Color.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        #Graph4_Label
        self.Graph4_Label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Graph 4", self.widget)
        self.Graph4_Label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Graph4_Label.setObjectName("Graph4_Label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph4_Label, 3, 0, 1, 1)

        #Graph4_Select
        self.Graph4_Select = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        self.Graph4_Select.setObjectName("Graph4_Select")
        self.Graph4_Select.addItems(Graphs)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph4_Select, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.Graph4_Select.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        #Graph4_Color
        self.Graph4_Color = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        self.Graph4_Color.setObjectName("Graph4_Color")
        self.Graph4_Color.addItems(Graph_Colors)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph4_Color, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.Graph4_Color.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        #Graph5_Label
        self.Graph_Label5 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Graph 5", self.widget)
        self.Graph_Label5.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.Graph_Label5.setObjectName("Graph_Label5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph_Label5, 4, 0, 1, 1)

        #Graph5_Select
        self.Graph5_Select = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        self.Graph5_Select.setObjectName("Graph5_Select")
        self.Graph5_Select.addItems(Graphs)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph5_Select, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.Graph5_Select.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        #Graph5_Color
        self.Graph5_Color = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget)
        self.Graph5_Color.setObjectName("Graph5_Color")
        self.Graph5_Color.addItems(Graph_Colors)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.Graph5_Color, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        self.Graph5_Color.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)


    def onActivated(self, text, axis):  
        print(text)
        self.axes.clear()
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01) 
        s = cos(2*pi*t) 
        self.axes.plot(t,s)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def UseCurrentTimeButton(self, enabled):

        if enabled:
            print("enabled")
            self.EndTime.setEnabled(False)
        else:
            print("disabled")
            self.EndTime.setEnabled(True)
            self.EndTime.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
            self.EndTime.setTime(QTime.currentTime())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Edit your code, the bottom is wonky, and the indentations are off.

Comment: @zippo Change `onActivated(self, text, axis): ` to `onActivated(self, text): `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use a `QGraphicsView` necessarily, you can use any widget, what you have to do is insert a layout and add the canvas to the layout.

```
    [...]
    t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
    s = sin(2*pi*t)

    figure = Figure()
    self.axes = figure.gca()
    self..set_title("title")
    self..plot(t,s)
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
    self.canvas.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)
    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.graphicsView)
    lay.addWidget(self.canvas)
    [...]
def onActivated(self, text):  
    print(text)
    self.axes.clear()
    t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01) 
    s = cos(2*pi*t) 
    self.axes.plot(t,s)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: If your answer was helpful, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I did but I am two new for it to show. One  issue I have now is when I attempt to update the plot upon combo event it crashes :-(

Comment: I have tried several methods, Including redraing the plot with new variables.    def onActivated(self, text):  
        print(text)
        t = arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)
        s = sin(2*pi*t)
        axes.plot(t,s)

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47384116/edit) add what you have tried.

Comment: Im thinking it is a scope issue.

Comment: Exactly you have member of the class to the necessary elements.

Comment: I am in the same class but a different def

Comment: Bone changes for example: `axes` to `self.axes`

Comment: No change, still dumps

Comment: Already update my answer, do not forget to import to without from numpy.

Comment: I Posted/updated the complete updated code in the question (tried to get the indent correct) still crashed on event. I had to move the your order around a little to get it to run.

Comment: @zippo Change `onActivated(self, text, axis): ` to `onActivated(self, text): `

Comment: Nada, still dumps :-( Thanks for all the help! by the way

Comment: I have uploaded my test to the following link, check it https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/8c7ad6e24a486f10c7dda664245b7a0f

Comment: I put it into a new file and its seems to run! Thanks again so much for the help!

Comment: @zippo Sir, when a question is of help, it should be marked as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/tour